# get the specific value from array of object using id in java Script

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to get a specific value from the array of the object using object Id.

```
array = [ 
         { f_name: a, l_name: q, id: 1},
         { f_name: b, l_name: w, id: 2},
         { f_name: c, l_name: e, id: 3},
        ]
```

How to get f_name value only using the id:1 ?..

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor.

Comment: Please search your title before asking

Answer (score 1):

You can use filter for this

- filter returns all of the elements whichs elements id = 1 when the condition is `element.id === 1` as a new array
- then print out the name of this element

```js
let array = [ 
         { "f_name": "a", "l_name": "q", "id": 1},
         { "f_name": "b", "l_name": "w", "id": 2},
         { "f_name": "c", "l_name": "e", "id": 3},
        ]
        
        
let result = array.filter((element) => element.id===1);
 console.log(result[0].f_name);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const array = [ 
 { f_name: a, l_name: q, id: 1},
 { f_name: b, l_name: w, id: 2},
 { f_name: c, l_name: e, id: 3},
];

array.filter(a => a.id === 1);//returns { f_name: a, l_name: q, id: 1}
```

More info on filter and array manipulation can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)